# How to set thread number when running tensorflow sample on Android?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

As we know, the android demo of tensorflow is multi-thread. So how can I change it to the single-thread mode?

Comment: Please avoid asking such questions here...be program specific

Comment: We actually ask that developers ask TensorFlow usage questions on stackoverflow with the tag TensorFlow, so that we can keep our github issue queue to actionable items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this from Java right now. A value for intra-op parallelism is automatically picked in [local_device.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc#L38) matching the number of cores detected on your device. If you just want to test, you could overwrite the value there.

Inter-op parallelism is currently always 1 on mobile -- only one op runs at a time.

More generally in native code intra and inter op parallism can be set when creating your Session object. e.g.:

```
tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
tensorflow::ConfigProto& config = options.config;
config.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(num_threads);
Session session = tensorflow::NewSession(options);
```

This will override the automatically picked value. See [benchmark_model.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc#L56) for an example.

If you want to set this from Java, you would have to add a parameter to  [TensorFlowInferenceInterface.initializeTensorFlow()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/jni/tensorflow_inference_jni.cc#L100).

We're switching to the Java API soon, though, so it will be easier to access the SessionOptions to set the value then.